# "New Document" button on ribbon is grayed out in the "Master Page Gallery" for subsites

Tags: 2013, document-library, internet-explorer

On a subsite I'm trying to add a "JavaScript Display Template" to my "Master Page Gallery" but the "New Document" button is greyed out.  I've ran into this problem with "Compatibility View" set to both "On" or "Off".  I am a site collection admin and in the "Owners" group for each site.  The button is available on the root site but not on the subsite

[image]

How can I fix this?

FYI - I've tested with IE11 and IE 10.  Also, I'm pursuing this on the [Microsoft SharePoint Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/e52d268f-e270-4b21-b6c5-c26090f3015b/new-document-button-on-ribbon-not-working-in-the-master-page-gallery-in-internet-explorer-10-?forum=sharepointgeneral)

Comment: When you select your file, does it not allow you to change the content type afterwards in the properties form ?

Comment: @CameronVerhelst Bingo! It does allow me to change the content type afterwards in the properties form.  I'll have to use this as a workaround for now.